# why execution time for this python code increases each call?

Tags: python, performance, time

```
import time
word = {"success":0, "desire":0, "effort":0, ...}
def cleaner(x):
    dust = ",./<>?;''[]{}\=+_)(*&^%$#@!`~"
    for letter in x:
        if letter in dust:
            x = x[0:x.index(letter)]+x[x.index(letter)+1:]
        else:
            pass
    return x #alhamdlillah it worked 31.07.12
print "input text to analyze"
itext = cleaner(raw_input()).split()
t = time.clock()
for iword in itext:
    if iword in word:
        word[iword] += 1
    else:
        pass
print t
print len(itext)
```

every time i call the code, t will increase. can anyone explain the underlying concept/reason behind this. perhaps in terms of system process? thank you very much, programming lads.

Comment: WHat is the point of your question? Where is your code doing the calculation of the execution time?

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but you should really look into [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) instead of your `cleaner` function.

Comment: @Gordon, you'd have to use `unicode.translate` to be able to change the length of the string. `dust=set(dust);x = "".join(c for c in x if c not in dust)` should be better

Comment: @gnibbler - I don't think you're correct about that. Try: `'foo!!bar'.translate(None, '!')`

Comment: @GordonBailey, Ah, that's what the help says too. I see they slipped that in in Python2.6

Comment: thank you evryone. i did not know of this, im a rank beginner anyway. @Gordon, thank you but i dont understand most of what the help says, too bad for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you're printing out the *current time* **each time you run the script**

That's how time works, it advances, constantly.

Comment: +1 for discovering a secret ("_That's how time works, it advances, constantly._") ;)

Comment: Except for on Windows when it sometimes goes backward a little bit. MS must have decided it's ok since they still haven't fixed it

Comment: Microsoft is above the laws of the time, space and logic, of course.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to measure the time taken for your `for` loop (between the first call to `time.clock()` and the end), print out the *difference* in times:

```
print time.clock() - t
```

Comment: Or, use the `timeit` module, which can give a more accurate answer (it does its best to factor out things other than your code that can affect it).

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the current time... of course it increases every time you run the code.

From the python documentation for `time.clock()`:

> On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number
>   expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition
>   of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function
>   of the same name, but in any case, this is the function to use for
>   benchmarking Python or timing algorithms.
>
> On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the
>   first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the
>   Win32 function QueryPerformanceCounter(). The resolution is typically
>   better than one microsecond.

Answer (score 0):

`time.clock()` returns the elapsed **CPU time** since the process was created. CPU time is based on how many cycles the CPU spent in the context of the process. It is a monotonic function during the lifetime of a process, i.e. if you call `time.clock()` several times in the same execution, you will get a list of increasing numbers. The difference between two successive invocations of `clock()` could be less than the elasped wall-clock time or more, depending on wheather the CPU was not running at 100% (e.g. there was some waiting for I/O) or if you have a multithreaded program which consumes more than 100% of CPU time (e.g. multicore CPU with 2 threads using 75% each -> you'd get 150% of the wall-clock time). But if you call `clock()` once in one process, then rerun the program again, you might get lower value than the one before, if it takes less time to process the input in the new process.

What you should be doing instead is to use `time.time()` which returns the current Unix timestamp with fractional (subsecond) precision. You should call it once before the processing is started and once after that and subtract the two values in order to compute the wall-clock time elapsed between the two invocations.

Note that on Windows `time.clock()` returns the elapsed wall-clock time since the process was started. It is like calling `time.time()` immediately at the beginning of the script and then subtracting the value from later calls to `time.time()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good library called [jackedCodeTimerPy](https://github.com/BebeSparkelSparkel/jackedCodeTimerPY) that works better than the time module. It also has some clever error checking so you may want to try it out.

Using jackedCodeTimerPy your code should look like this:

```
# import time
from jackedCodeTimerPY import JackedTiming
JTimer = JackedTiming()

word = {"success":0, "desire":0, "effort":0}
def cleaner(x):
    dust = ",./<>?;''[]{}\=+_)(*&^%$#@!`~"
    for letter in x:
        if letter in dust:
            x = x[0:x.index(letter)]+x[x.index(letter)+1:]
        else:
            pass
    return x #alhamdlillah it worked 31.07.12
print "input text to analyze"
itext = cleaner(raw_input()).split()

# t = time.clock()
JTimer.start('timer_1')
for iword in itext:
    if iword in word:
        word[iword] += 1
    else:
        pass
# print t
JTimer.stop('timer_1')
print JTimer.report()
print len(itext)
```

It gives really good reports like

```
label            min          max         mean        total    run count
-------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
imports  0.00283813   0.00283813   0.00283813   0.00283813             1
loop     5.96046e-06  1.50204e-05  6.71864e-06  0.000335932           50
```

I like how it gives you statistics on it and the number of times the timer is run.

It's simple to use. If i want to measure the time code takes in a for loop i just do the following:

```
from jackedCodeTimerPY import JackedTiming
JTimer = JackedTiming()

for i in range(50):
  JTimer.start('loop')  # 'loop' is the name of the timer
  doSomethingHere = 'This is really useful!'
  JTimer.stop('loop')
print(JTimer.report())  # prints the timing report
```

You can can also have multiple timers running at the same time.

```
JTimer.start('first timer')
JTimer.start('second timer')
do_something = 'amazing'
JTimer.stop('first timer')

do_something = 'else'
JTimer.stop('second timer')

print(JTimer.report())  # prints the timing report
```

There are more use example in the repo. Hope this helps.

https://github.com/BebeSparkelSparkel/jackedCodeTimerPY